# How to set selected value of COREUI multiselect?

Tags: html, jquery, json, core-ui

I this json response from an API.

```
 {"first_name":"Person 1","last_name":"Person 1","email":"person@test.com","role":2,"properties":[1,2]}
```

And the following coreui element:

```
<select class="form-multi-select" id="edit_properties" name="multi-select-edit_properties" multiple="" data-coreui-search="true" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
      <option value="1">consequatur</option>
      <option value="2">dolore</option>
      <option value="3">ab</option>
      <option value="4">eum</option>
      <option value="5">maxime</option>
</select>
```

I tried using this jquery code:

```
$("#edit_properties").val([data.properties]);
```

No errors in console, and the select element does not set selected values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the multi-select to render pre-selected values, each option must have an extra attribute `selected="selected"`.

```html
<select class="form-multi-select" id="edit_properties" name="multi-select-edit_properties" multiple="" data-coreui-search="true" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">consequatur</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">dolore</option>
      <option value="3">ab</option>
      <option value="4">eum</option>
      <option value="5">maxime</option>
</select>
```

You can achieve this by adding the `selected` attribute programmatically, when you get the response from the API.

For example

```js
var response = JSON.parse('{"first_name":"Person 1","last_name":"Person 1","email":"person@test.com","role":2,"properties":[1,2]}');

// Get the reference of the html element using the coreui js API
var multiselect = coreui.MultiSelect.getInstance(document.querySelector("#edit_properties"));

response.properties.forEach(function(elem) {
    document.querySelector(`#edit_properties option[value='${elem}']`).setAttribute("selected", "selected")
});

// update the element to render the selected options
multiselect.update();
```

Useful links:

- https://coreui.io/docs/getting-started/javascript/#programmatic-api
- https://coreui.io/docs/forms/multi-select/#basic-example

Comment: Thank you for your help. However I am getting the following error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: coreui is not defined```

even after importing coreui.bundle.min.js, and coreui-utils.js.

Comment: I got it to load. however calling ```update()``` results in the following: ```Cannot read properties of null (reading 'update')```

Comment: Which version of coreui are you using?

Comment: Hi, Im using coreui-pro 4.2.0

Comment: I got it, it seems that I dont need to import coreui bundle.js and coreui.util.js when I already have this:
```import * as coreui from '@coreui/coreui-pro'
window.coreui = coreui;```